# Does the Mapbox Maps SDK v10 replace Mapbox-iOS-SDK 6.4.0?

Tags: ios, mapbox, mapbox-ios

I'm confused by these two competing Mapbox SDKs for iOS. Currently, I have the `Mapbox-iOS-SDK 6.4.0` Cocoapod pod installed in my iOS application. I see there is a new pod available called `MapboxMaps 10.0.1`. Does `MapboxMaps 10.0.1` replace `Mapbox-iOS-SDK 6.4.0`? Is this the new iteration of the iOS SDK with a new pod name and a substantially higher version number? And would there be a good reason not to opt for the new pod over the old?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

v10 uses Metal, 6.x uses OpenGL. OpenGL is officially deprecated by Apple starting with macOS Mojave 10.14. Apple will not support OpenGL in the future. There are other improvements as well.

From what I can tell, v10 requires rewriting existing code. That could be a consideration for not updating.

Comment: Hi Tom, could you please suggest any resources to implement v10 of Mapbox SDK for iOS?

Comment: The Mapbox SDK for iOS is now at version 11.0. Download at https://docs.mapbox.com/ios/maps/guides/